# Meshes in moveit setup assistant

Tags: ros, moveit, mesh, moveit-tutorial, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Pretty quick question: can meshes be used and rendered in urdf files for the moveit_setup_assistant?  I ask because currently, when I try to load a urdf with a reference to a .stl file, I get the following error:

[rospack] Error: no package/stack given
[librospack]: error while executing command

And mesh files don't load.  Does anyone know why this is?

EDIT: I'm actually wondering - is this just a limitation of rviz?  Are there certain ways one would have to have their urdf formatted to make all the meshes appear properly?  Will only certain filetypes render?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67577/meshes-in-moveit-setup-assistant/) by [aespielberg](https://answers.ros.org/users/147/aespielberg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2013-07-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-09-28**:
`URDF` can reference to mesh files ([example](http://answers.ros.org/question/9613/how-to-import-stl-files-into-urdf-files/)) and RViz can render mesh ([example](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/Environment_Representation/Rviz)), but I'm not sure about importing URDF that refers to `.stl` files.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-09-28**:
But the following error seems more generic than specific issue of URDF-STL.

```
[rospack] Error: no package/stack
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you try sourced the `setup.sh` in that terminal? I think I had that issue once and it was just that I was forgetting to do so.

---

Originally posted by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) with karma: 700 on 2017-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0